# Ordering results from a Doctrine DQL query with FIELD

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have the following DQL in a Symfony repository class:

```
    $dql = '
        SELECT cg, field(cgr.channel_id, :channel) as HIDDEN field
        FROM \CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuide cg
        JOIN \CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow cgr
        WHERE cg.gender = :gender
        ORDER BY cg.name ASC, field DESC
    ';

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter('gender', $gender)
        ->setParameter('channel', $channel->getId())
        ->getResult();
```

`CourseGuide` has a member variable of as below so there is a relationship between it and `CourseGuideRow`:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $rows;
```

`CourseGuide.orm.yml` (snippet):

```
oneToMany:
    rows:
        targetEntity: CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow
        mappedBy: courseGuide
        cascade: ["persist","remove"]
```

`CourseGuideRow.orm.yml` (snippet):

```
manyToOne:
    courseGuide:
        targetEntity: CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuide
        inversedBy: rows
        joinColumn:
            nullable: false
            name: course_guide_id
```

Running this code gives me this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 24: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'field'

In a nutshell, what I am trying to achieve is pull out all the "CourseGuides" with their associated "CourseGuideRows" and order the "CourseGuideRows" by the channel_id that I pass in. So for example this could be `2`, so I would like `2` to be first in the list, e.g. `IN (2, 4, 5)`.

Comment: Your field function is not recognised as it's not part of the Doctrine core functions. You an either create your own or (which I would recommend) use `DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field` from `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` (https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

Comment: @qooplmao Thanks, i'm going to have a go at sorting them with PHP. If i'm having any issues with that then i'll look at installing `DoctrineExtensions`.